# How can I solve these issues with my program? (Many issues explained inside)

Tags: java

This question is not for the faint of heart and will be time consuming..

I am learning Java, and I was wondering if anyone could walk me through my program to tell me what I did wrong and how I can fix it so that I can learn.

My whole program (in case this is needed): http://pastie.org/private/xpbgpypetvfmivcs88gbcq

Assignment:

> Not allowed to use global variables!
>   You have been asked to write a program
>   to grade the results of a true-false
>   quiz and display the results in
>   tabular form. The quiz consists of 10
>   questions. The data file for this
>   problem consists of 1 set of correct
>   responses (answerkey) on line one and
>   succeeding lines containing a four
>   digit student identification number
>   followed by that student's 10
>   responses. (The number of students
>   taking the quiz in currently unknown.)
>
> The data file is in the form :
>
> TFFTFTTFTT
>
> 0461 TTFTTFTFTT
>
> 3218 TFFTTTTTFT
>
> .....................
>
> ....................
>
> Your program should read the key and
>   store it in a one dimensional array.
>   It should then read and process each
>   succeeding line, storing the student
>   identification numbers in a one
>   dimensional array and the grades in
>   two separate one dimensional arrays-
>   one for numeric grades and the for
>   letter grades.
>
> Numeric grades are converted to letter
>   according to the following system :
>   A(10), B(9), C(8-7), D (6-5), F(4-0).
>
> Program output should include the
>   following :
>
> 1. Each Student's four digit identification number, their numeric
>      grade and their letter grade.
> 2. A printed count of how many students took the quiz.
> 3. The numeric quiz average for the entire class.
> 4. A frequency count of the number of A's, B's, C's,D's and F's for the
>      entire class.

EDIT:

Oh, hey. Sorry, I am still getting the hang of how to do all of this :(  Alright, here goes.

The program is not compiling, and I am pretty sure it's down to my logic. (As well as some syntactical stuff).

What I'm having trouble with:
1) How to pass all of the parameters to each of the different methods, as seen here. What I would LIKE to do is have all of my values that I return such as answerKey, studentAnswers, numericGrade, average etc be up here so that I can use them and print them. But I do not know how to do that.

```
int[] numericGrade = computeNumericGrade(answerKey, studentAnswers);
      int[] letterGrade = computeLetterGrade(numericGrade);
      double average = average(numericGrade);
      int gradeTally = gradeTally(letterGrade);
      int studentCount = studentCount(numericGrade);
```

2) I cannot figure out how to individually check through each of the T or F values and check if it corresponds with the T or F in the answer key, as seen below.

What I am trying to do is to check through each letter at a specific element, and if the value is "correct" or == to answerKey, then add to the total in numericGrade for that element.

```
public static int[] computeNumericGrade(int[] answerKey, int[] studentAnswers) {
      int[] numericGrade = new int[50];
      int total = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < 50;i++) {
        for(int a = 0;a == 10;a++) {
          total = studentAnswers[i].charAt(a);
          if(total == answerKey[i]) numericGrade[i]++;
        }
      }
    return numericGrade;
    }
```

3) I do not know how to return all of these different values, as I need them all above! I want this set of code to check the letter grade of each element and if this element is found, ++ the variable that corresponds to it, so I know how many of this letter grade was called.

```
public static int gradeTally(String[] letterGrade) {
      int a, b, c, d, f = 0;
      for(int i = 0;i < letterGrade.length;i++) {
        if(letterGrade[i] == 'A') a++;
        else if (letterGrade[i] == 'B') b++;
        else if (letterGrade[i] == 'C') c++;
        else if (letterGrade[i] == 'D') d++;
        else if (letterGrade[i] == 'F') f++;
      }
      return a + b + c + d + f;
    }
```

4) I can't figure this out... I think I am close. Here, I am trying to read the file, tokenize it, and then for each token, add it to the array 1 by 1. However, I don't think that's it's doing that properly, but I can't check since I can't get it to compile...

```
public static String[] getData() throws IOException {
      int[] studentID = new int[50];
      String[] studentAnswers = new String[50];
      int total = 0;

      String line = reader.readLine();
      strTkn = new StringTokenizer(line);
      String answerKey = strTkn.nextToken();

      while(line != null) {
        studentID[total] = Integer.parseInt(strTkn.nextToken());
        studentAnswers[total] = strTkn.nextToken();
        total++;
      }
    return studentAnswers;
    }
```

I am now done editing my post. I hope this is sufficient :)

Comment: Don't link code externally.  Paste it in.  Also describe in your own words what you _think_ you have done, and what you wanted to do.

Comment: What is the specific problem with your program as it stands?  People will not be willing to analyse large chunks of code unless you can provide more detailed information, stack traces, sample output, etc.

Comment: You've asked "what's wrong with my program" but you haven't told us why you think there's something wrong with it -- e.g., what is it doing that you think it shouldn't be doing (or vice-versa)? Even with your caveat that the question isn't for the faint of heart, you're asking a *lot* to just say "Here it is, what's wrong?" You need to break that down a bit. BTW, on *first glance*, you're breaking the "no global variables" rule with those statics (`infile`, `inReader`) at the outset of your class.

Comment: "Don't link code externally. Paste it in" hear hear! However, don't paste the entire program asking "what did I do wrong", post the parts that aren't working, or post a general "pseudo code" outline of what you're doing. Do that if you're code "works" i.e. each line does what it's told, but the overall program doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: P.S. Don't be put off by the nagative comments, we do want to help, but we'll help in our way, and on our terms.

Comment: Each of the comments above are dead-on. I'd love to assist you in figuring out what is wrong with it. But, for one...I'm not going to do your homework for you. As Thorbjørn stated, paste your code in your answer, break it down and tell us what each method is doing. I've started a question off doing this and halfway through it, I figured it out.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions guys, I am currently editing my first post for it to be better. I know exactly why it was crappy before :)

Comment: P.S. - I would've given him a bit more time to correct this question before giving him a -1    ;)

Comment: I can only edit so quickly :(

Comment: We need a "Most comments without a single answer" badge.

Comment: I would be honored to receive such a badge.

(And at the same time, so depressed :P)

I have a feeling no one's going to answer me now that I am -1. *Sigh* :(

Comment: Please **nail down** the root problem into flavor of an SSCCE (http://sscce.org), then we'll look further. Do **not** say like "what am I doing wrong?", this way we'll get nowhere. Rather give the shortest possible executabele code snippet which reproduces **exactly** the problem you have (thus, SSCCE) and elaborate in detail *why* that is a problem (i.e. what is the functional requirement? what did you expect? what did happen instead?). Do not post 1000 lines of irrelevant code. Also see http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html Good luck (really).

Comment: +1 because this is an example of how a new user *should* take on the feedback from members of the StackOverflow community if they expect to be helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you realize from the comments that this is kind of difficult to help with.

I'm not sure how much it will help, but I'd like to give some general tips about how you might approach this.

First of all, I'd probably throw away what you have and start over.  I've NEVER regretted throwing away code--it always helps your code in the long run and you learn a lot more the second time through.

Secondly, start small.  Make something that works--even if it just reads in the values and proves they were read in properly, then expand it.  Test CONSTANTLY.  Whenever you add to your code, add a line to your test to ensure the new code works as well as everything that has come before it

This way if anything breaks, you'll know exactly what broke it--the last thing you edited.

To do this kind of quick test, you should either learn to use JUnit for unit testing or have a main made just for testing so that you can hit a single button and get an immediate answer.  (JUnit really isn't hard and it's built into Eclipse.  Oh yeah, next hint).  .

USE ECLIPSE or NetBeans!

These are all things that experienced programmers just know and do automatically.  A little investment of time and effort in the beginning can save a LOT of pain in the long run.

Comment: Or IntelliJ - better than both of them.

Comment: Judging by the experience level of the askers, I'd say using industry strength tools and practices is not advisable at such an early stage. There are better, more focussed **teaching** tools available, such as BlueJ which I'd recommend before Eclipse/NB/IDEA.

Comment: BlueJ is nice I used it quite a bit, but it doesn't have the instant error detection.  It's not like it makes you "Lazy" or anything, it just stops you from having to compile before you see your errors which can save a lot of time.  Also used IntelliJ for about 5 years.  I still haven't decided if it's better than the others, maybe a little but no where near to compensate for it's lack of FOSS.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are still stuck on compiling, I will try to help you get over that stumbling block before addressing the logic in the code.

There are rules which will cause the code not to compile, including syntactic rules, but these are not generally referred to as "logic". I would describe logic errors as the program running but not doing what you want it to. Anyhoo...

Many of the compiler errors are of the form:

```
someField cannot be resolved
```

This happens when you are trying to reference a variable that can't be "seen" at that point by the compiler. In your case this is because you have declared the variables in places where they can't be seen, when you want to reference them.

This is the case with several of the fields in your `main()` method. This is down to an issue of *scope*. To be able to refer to variables, such as `answerKey` or `studentAnswers`, they must be in scope. Global scope is when you can reference a variable from anywhere, this is what you're trying to avoid. You have *declared* the variables `answerKey`, `studentAnswers` within a method, like so:

```
public static String[] getData() throws IOException {
  // other code

  String[] studentAnswers = new String[50];

  // other code 

  String answerKey = strTkn.nextToken();

  // other code
}
```

What you have done with these declarations, is say that `studentAnswers` and `answerKey` are "within the scope of the `getData()` method". This means that they cannot be referenced elsewhere, and is the cause of the compiler error within `main()`.

One way to do this is to declare the variables globally - such as `public static String answerKey;` just under `public class GradeResults {`, but you have been asked specifically not to do this (and for good reason, which I won't get into).

A different way I would recommend is to "encapsulate" the variables. This is a fancy programming word which roughly means wrap up the data and behaviour into an object, and let the object decide how to behave, and change itself. I'll give you one way you could get started with this (there are many, many ways you could do it). That is to encapsulate all the information about a student within an object, which we can create, using a new class, called `Student`.

```
 // this is a new class, and will have to be saved in a file called Student.java
public class Student {

    // these are field declarations
    private int id;
    private String answers;

    // this is the constructor, it creates a new instance of Student
    public Student(int newStudentsId, String newStudentsAnswers) {
        // these lines take the parameters (in brackets on the line above)
        // and assign them to the fields of this instance
        this.id = newStudentsId;
        this.answers = newStudentsAnswers;
    }

    // after this you could have getters for the fields,
    // these are often referred to as "accessors" in introductory texts
    // this is all I'll give you of this example, to get you started

} // End of class Student.java
```

---

The remaining compiler errors you see are slightly easier:

```
Incompatible operand types String and char
```

In the code:

```
public static int gradeTally(String[] letterGrade) {
  // other code
    if(letterGrade[i] == 'A') a++;  // error on this line
```

The type of the variable referenced by `letterGrade[i]` is a String, and the constant `'A'` is a char. There are two choices for fixing this

- change the `'A'` to `"A"`, notice double quotations instead of single, single is for `char` types, double is for `String` types. Other choice is:
- change the type of the `letterGrade` array to `char[] letterGrade` where it's declared (in the parameter list of the method signature).

This is roughly the same problem which is causing the compiler error:

```
Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the primitive type int
```

With the code:

```
total = studentAnswers[i].charAt(a);
```

`charAt` is a method of the `String` class, therefore `studentAnswers[i]` must refer to a variable of type `String`. But it is declared as `int[] studentAnswers`, so there's a "type mismatch" there.

There's a lot to think about here, and I've left plenty of gaps which you'll have to fill in yourself. A good introductory text on object oriented programming with Java (for example [Objects First With Java](http://www.bluej.org/objects-first/)) should cover everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a quick look through points 2) and 3):

2) I presume the aim here is to determine the number of correct answers by checking which elements in the `studentAnswers` array equal the elements in `answerKey`.  Assuming this is the goal then my tips would be:

- Why are you returning an array?  Surely it would make more sense to return a single integer equal to the total number of matches?
- You should be able to structure the code as a single loop, whereby you iterate using an index (e.g. i), comparing the elements of the two arrays.
- The reference to charAt is wrong; this is a method on the `java.lang.String` class, but you aren't using `String`s at all.

3) You should consider returning a different object capable of storing the grade tally.  For example, you could consider a `Map<Character, Integer>` where the map's keys are the grades and the values are the grade frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Java's an object-oriented language.  Think in terms of objects.  This is little more than C or Fortran written in Java.  There's no encapsulation or information hiding that I can see.

It's probably due to the fact that it's a first programming class, and your professor might not understand objects.  But that's where you ought to be headed with Java.

I'd expect to see classes like Student, Class, Grade (maybe as an enumeration), ReportCard.  Instead, all I see are primitives.  Someday you'll think of this as an example of how to write Java poorly.